# Excel macro - Value compare

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, vba

I actually need help on the thinking process and options, and not really on the coding.

I want users to enter their zip code. Then I need to look in what Range the zip code is.
Edit: Because I'm from Belgium, the zip code is 4 numbers long (1000, 1500, 8380, ...)

```
Zip code: 2800
Range between;
1000-1999
2000-2999
3000-3999
4000-4999
If the range is between one of the following, display all zip codes for that range
Else do nothing
```

I've come up with an If, Else structure. But I'm wondering whether there's a better option?

```
Zip code: 2800
If zip code > 3999 then
   'Select all zipcodes within this range
   'Range(" .. ").Copy Destination:=Sheets...
ElsIf zip code > 2999 then
   'Select all zipcodes within this range
   'Range(" .. ").Copy Destination:=Sheets...
Elsif zipcode  ....
```

Thank you.

@@@@@@@@@@@@@

**Openshac**

I've come up with this.

```
x = 1
Sheets("Reference").Select
For i = 1 to 115
    If Range("A" & i).value > 5999 and Range("A" & i).value < 6000 then
        Range("A" & i).copy Destination:=Sheets("Design").Range("A" & x)
        x = x + 1
    End if
Next i
```

Comment: What is "Do something"? Does it change for each zipcode range?

Comment: Hang on, I'll change it.

Comment: hmmmm which (Integer ??) number is greater than (>) 5999 and at the same time is smaller than (<) 6000   ..... and bad bad bad hardcoding! So does it mean for any given ZIP code you want to display all ZIP codes from your table that are within the sane thousands-range .... I formulate a seperate answer on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a switch statement?

```
Select Case zipCode
Case 1000 To 1999
    'Do something
Case 2000 To 2999
    'Do something
Case 3000 To 3999
    'Do something
Case 4000 To 4999
    'Do something
Case Else
    ' Do nothing
End Select
```

What you've got is fine, it's just a case of what is most readable to you / easiest for you to maintain.  You shouldn't notice any difference in performance

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering whether or not to use Cases. Perhaps you could help me with selecting the range too I need to copy?

Comment: #Tom was the Range(" .. ").Copy Destination:=Sheets... code in your original question?

Comment: No, I changed it shakk understood what the Do something was supposed to be. Just asked you if you could help, out of curiosity.

Comment: ah OK I see, what exactly are you try to do in each if statement?

Comment: well I've changed if else structure into a Case structure (this is much easier to interpret). So lets say zipcode = 2800. It runs through the cases, finds the correct case. In the case I would need a bit of code that does the following; copy all zipcodes from a worksheet that are also within this range, and paste them in a different worksheet.

Comment: If you have a look at my original question, I've added something for you.

Comment: #Tom, sorry but I'm not expert in Excel VBA, but I'd think that a quick google and you'll should find an answer.  It's been done hundreds of times before by people.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

reading the various comments I am still not clear what is the question. I recon you provide an input ZIP (ARG = 2800) and you want to display all ZIPs of a data table where the thousand digit matches the thousand digit of the input, in other words

```
ZIPdata.ZIP BETWEEN INT(ARG / 1000) * 1000 AND INT(ARG / 1000) * 1000 + 999
```

without any VBA you can define an advanced filter with a calculated criterium based on the formula above, the criterium formula would be

```
=AND(B9>=$B$2;B9<=$E$2)

    B9 being the ZIP in your first data record (not the heading)
    B2 being the lower bound using above formulae
    E2 being the upper bound using above formulae
```

Alternatively you can define an Autofilter across ZIP and feed lowe and upper bound into the autofilter criteria via VBA.